# TextInputLayout as parallelogram

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, shapes, textinputlayout

I wanna create TextInputLayout in shape parallelogram. I have it with ConstraintLayout.
I would like my textinputlayout to be in the shape of a parallelogram. I don't know how to enter such a slope... Here is a fragment of my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="0dp"
app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="0dp"
app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="0dp"
app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="0dp"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="255dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="20dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="hint"/>
    
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I tried many ways, including SlantedTextView, but it didn't help. It's probably a matter of adding a few features, but I'm a beginner and I don't know what it should look like...

Many ways... For example SlantedTextView

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.